# Eclipse MyFaces Wizard?

Tags: eclipse, plugins, wizard, myfaces

I am new to java development and a customer uses MyFaces for MVC based website development. While I know the ASP.NET based MVC Framework from Microsoft and the possibility of easily adding new pages via IDE methods (context menues, wizards, etc.), in eclipse everything has to be done manually.

For adding a simple new website, I have to manually edit at least five files. I need a new jsp file, a bean, an application server, a business object, the navigation has to be extended, some faces configuration files need to be altered for mapping between pages and beans, a couple of string files have to be edited for language support and so on.

Is there some sort of plugin for eclipse available that is able to support on that?

Answer (score 0):

The closest environment you can find to manage all those resources is [**WTP (Web Tool Platform)**](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/)

> extends the Eclipse platform with tools for developing Web and Java EE applications.
>   It includes source and graphical editors for a variety of languages, wizards and built-in applications to simplify development, and tools and APIs to support deploying, running, and testing apps.

You can [install it through the update manager](http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/updates/) of eclipse.